# c# listview class - lock possibility to resize columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using windows forms and listviewclass. I wish to lock possibility to resize columns width by user. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this little hack:

```
    private void listviewname_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        e.NewWidth = listviewname.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
    }
```

But this doesnt handles the cursor

Comment: @Marco, your code allow user to change columns size. The user just will not see the animation resize :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate way (without create new method):

```
listView.ColumnWidthChanging += (e, sender) =>
{
    ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs arg = (ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs)sender;
    arg.Cancel = true;
    arg.NewWidth = lvAdSchedule.Columns[arg.ColumnIndex].Width;
};
```